# Attempting to parse out information in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

One of our projects is transferring our iPhone app to work in a windows phone. Since I knew nothing about xaml until about 5 days ago I thought I would volunteer and try to learn a few things.

The first link below is the xml for the main page

The second link below is what I would expect when I click on the term/semester.

Then below these links is the code I have done....

My problem is that I sort of bit off more than I can chew. I really don't understand how to get this information out. I read the xaml tutorial on MSDN, yet it didn't seem to help me out completely. So I commented out in my MainPage() method what I had and I hard coded in the terms/semesters. This isn't really going to help me much since it needs to be coming from xaml. I just wanted to see something done on my windows app that looked relatively like progress.

How do I parse out the information from the links? I am needing just a slight push in the right direction or maybe a link someone knows of that has some good xaml explanation that is relevant to do. I've read quite a bit so far but it isn't helping much.

http://www.usi.edu/webservices/iphone/USIINFOterms.xml

http://www.usi.edu/webservices/iphone/USIINFO201310.xml

```
namespace PhoneApp1
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemLine1 { get; set; }
        public string ItemLine2 { get; set; }
    }
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PageTitle.Text = "Terms";
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        Item item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = "Third Summer 2014";
        item.ItemLine2 = "Classes";
        list.Add(item);
        item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = "Second Summer 2014";
        item.ItemLine2 = "Classes";
        list.Add(item);
        item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = "First Summer 2014";
        item.ItemLine2 = "Classes";
        list.Add(item);
        item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = "Spring 2014";
        item.ItemLine2 = "classes";
        list.Add(item);
        item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = "Fall 2013";
        item.ItemLine2 = "Classes";
        list.Add(item);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ListBox1.ItemsSource = list));

        //WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        //wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        //wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.usi.edu/webservices/iphone/USIINFOterms.xml"));
    }
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationTitle.Text = e.Result;
    }
    private void ListBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null) PageTitle.Text = sender.ToString();
        if (e != null) PageTitle.Text = e.AddedItems.Count.ToString();
        IEnumerator ie = e.AddedItems.GetEnumerator();
        ie.MoveNext();
        if (e != null) ApplicationTitle.Text = ie.Current.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

So what i get after reading your question, the problem is parsing xml document in c#. I'm trying to help parsing the first page (the logic that you hardcoded currently), since the xml format is simpler than the second. Then you can take this example to parse the second xml. I am using linq to xml to parse xml in c#:

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
    List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
    foreach (var x in doc.Descendants("row"))
    {
        var values = x.Elements("value").ToList();
        var item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = values[0].Value;
        item.ItemLine2 = values[1].Value;
        list.Add(item);
    }
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ListBox1.ItemsSource = list));
}
```

Comment: dont forget to add `using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: Very useful. I have modified my code quite a bit and I believe I need to make a new thread to ask the question as the modification and question now is different.